# Referenced file contains errors (http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd)

Tags: hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name = "connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property> 
<property name = "connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property> 
<property name = "connection.username">hr</property> 
<property name = "connection.password">kiran</property> 
<property name = "connection.pool_size">10</property> 
<property name = "dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
<property name = "hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name = "show_sql">true</property>
<mapping resource = "resources/student.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am getting error in the first line of the hibernate configuration and mapping files in web application (Dynamic Web Project). I am not getting errors in stand alone application (java project).

Comment: can you share you full configuration?

Comment: I am using apache-tomcat-7.0.26 server  and hibernate-release-4.3.8.Final

Comment: please edit the question and put your code on your question

Comment: i have edited the question and posted the code.